# I have a Fresh Mac System Now I want to Install RHO Mobile Installer for Cross Platform So How can i do it?

Tags: iphone, android, macos, rhodes, rhomobile

I am New in this field.I want to install RHO Mobile Installer In my Mac System.I don't know anything about it so please give me some basic steps for that.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhosync/install#mac-os--linux doesn't provide enough info for you?

Comment: hey id dousn't provides enought information. in first not even installing rhodes frm sudo gem install. so from some other sites i came to know that i have to make environment for ruby and rubygem first. i did it but after that gem install rhodes says you dont have updated version. so theirs nothing like straight forward steps to make it work with rhodes in that site. even in windows and in rhostudio its not taking updates. i tried all my level best but still not getting right way.